# Raspberry Pi 2 ITX motherboard conversion

Tags: kodi, media-server, hard-drive, htpc

I am planning on building a new media center unit using a Raspberry Pi 2 however I have some specific requirements:

- Unit requires an RPi base-board like the fairywren
- Need to connect 3+ SATA devices (HDD / Blu-Ray)
- ALL ports must be located on the rear of the unit, as with a conventional HTPC unit.

I have been looking into the fairywren, but not sure if this is compliant with the RPi 2?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk5lJbnZEdU

http://www.geekroo.com.au/products/795

Can anyone recommend any products I can use to connect SATA devices to an RPi 2, and if there are any alternatives to the fairywren?

Comment: Your second link is broken

Comment: @SteveRobillard - it's working for me :/

Comment: I get a nginx 404 page. Have you asked the makers of this product your questions. or checked the FAQ (they may have already answered at least the last of your 3 questions)?

Comment: Some of fairywen's own links are dead, lol.  If you need SATA why don't you just go with a cubieboard or something similar that has the connectors you want to start with?

Comment: How come you're not sure if it's compliant? The product page says it right there with bold red highlight: "This product is ONLY designed for the Raspberry Pi B. It is NOT compatible with Raspberry Pi 2 or B+!!"

Answer (score 0):

It should be electrically compatible, but the mounting holes are in different places and there isn't a spot for the second set of USB ports. If you desolder the second set of USB ports and drill your own mounting holes, it would be compatible. http://www.geekroo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/FK50-2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SATA to USB convertor like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJZJI84) and then access the SATA hard drives. The disadvantage of this method would be that you would get a slower speed when compared to SATA.

If you use a single 2.5 inch HDD, the pi should be able to power it directly if you enable the [high power mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=82823) on the B+ and Pi2. If you are using more than one 2.5 inch HD or 3.5 inch HD's then you'll have to use a powered USB connections to supply power to the Hard drive or the Pi would not boot or would have a lot of reboots.